# Are there any good extension method libraries available other than the one from MS, for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-2007

Much as the question states, there is [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.extensions.aspx) (part of [VSTO Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=46B6BF86-E35D-4870-B214-4D7B72B02BF9&displaylang=en))which offers a series of handy extension methods for calling Excel interop code from C#. Are there other 3rd party/open source libraries that ppl are aware of that can be used in the same way? i.e. to either hide parameters (of methods not already covered by the main extensions namespace) or provide other extenisable functionality such as for ranges, lists and other "enumerable" type objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Extensionmethod.net](http://www.extensionmethod.net/) is a website where people can post extension methods to a searchable database.

Additionally, there are quite a few projects over on Codeplex if you [search](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=extension%20method&ac=8).

Answer (score 0):

Using the codeplex I found the [EPPlus project](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)
 which uses the [ExcelPackage project](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/).

which provides advanced functionality for adding charts, formatting, and images when creating Excel workbooks without the Excel.Interop namespace.

Not exactly what I wanted (was looking for extensions to Excel.Interop) but its cool and I will check it out.

Checked [Extensionmethods.net](http://www.extensionmethod.net/) but there is nothing Excel or office specific.